# Mesh flattening

Tags: shaders, geometry-nodes

Hello I'm currently trying to flatten a mesh in the Z axis, my intention is that ive made a contour map in 3D, where the Z vertice values represent the values on the contour map. But I want to turn it 2D (flatten it) whilst preserving those Z values as the Z values are used for shader colouring later on. I've tried scaling it down to a small factor then multiplying out when I used a shader to colour it however it caused some Z fighting issues. I've also tried dividing the mesh down to a minute value with animation nodes to multiple out later for mesh colouring however with this way I cant seen to get the mesh flat enough, theres always a small bump.

Does anyone have any suggestion to a better way around this.

Comment: Sorry, I'm having difficulty picturing what your original "contour map" mesh looks like - any chance you could post a screenshot?

Comment: ...or provide your blend file so we can check it out

Comment: Go into edit mode for your mesh object. Select all vertices in vertex selection mode. Then scale the z-axis to 0. You may want to delete faces and/or edges.

Answer (score 4):

Just capture the position of each vertex with the node `Transfer Attribute` and separate *X/Y/Z*, then combine only the *X* and *Y axis*, and set the positions with the node `Set Position`. With this you have discarded *Z*.

The value for the *Z-axis*, on the other hand, you simply feed into a new socket of the node `Group Output`, give this value a name in the *Modifier Properties*.

With this name you can then capture this value in your shader nodes with the node `Attribute` and convert it into a color.

[image]

[image]